# JFrame stuck when opening another JFrame

Tags: java, arrays, jframe, jpanel

***EDIT2*: Tested it. It is definetily a problem with the new JPanel.**

***SOLUTION*: 
As proposed the answer is that i forgot to explicitely set my JPanel onto my JFrame. Change:**

```
setContentPane(contentPanetagesliste);
```

**to**

```
frame.setContentPane(contentPanetagesliste);
```

**and it works for me!**

---

My Problem is a strange behavior of JFrame.

In my code I got a radioButton on my MainFrame. When it is pressed it opens up the other Frame.

```
RadioBTNtagesliste.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    frame.setSize(590, 450); ...
```

In my new Frame I made a JPanel. Before adding the JPanel the other Frame didn't freeze, so I believe the problem got something to do with the new JPanel.

```
JPanel contentPanetagesliste;

contentPanetagesliste = new JPanel();

contentPanetagesliste.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
setContentPane(contentPanetagesliste);
```

In the end I add a JScrollPane to the JPanel (that's the reason why I had to make one) and make the JFrame visible.

```
JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(contentPanetagesliste);
frame.add(jsp);


frame.setVisible(true);
```

I absolutely have no clue how the new JPanel could interfere with the Main JFrame or the JPanel lying above the MainJFrame. I hope some of you can help me.

EDIT: because it wasn't clear to some: by stuck i mean unresponsive and when i move it, it goes blank grey.

**To the image: When I press the radio button to the far top right, the new window opens, is fully functional  but the old window is stuck.**

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4CRY.jpg)

---

For additional information I'll post the complete code from my action listener with explanation.

```
RadioBTNtagesliste.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            if(RadioBTNtagesliste.isSelected() == true){
                String Eintrag = HttpClass.httpRequestEintrag(usernamevar,EintragStringPK,"eintragTABLE");
                 JSONObject jsonObjectEintrag = new JSONObject(Eintrag); 
                int ProjektJSONlength = jsonObjectEintrag.length() - 1;

                frame.setSize(590, 450);
                JPanel contentPanetagesliste;

                contentPanetagesliste = new JPanel();

                contentPanetagesliste.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
                setContentPane(contentPanetagesliste);

                double[] temp = new double[ProjektJSONlength+2];
                temp[0] = 10;
                temp[1] = 30;
                for(int i = 0; i < ProjektJSONlength; i++){
                    temp[i+2] = 25;
                }

                double size[][] = {{2, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90,90, 2}, // Columns
                    temp}; // Rows                      
                contentPanetagesliste.setLayout(new TableLayout(size));                     
                String label[] = {"Eintrag Nr.", "Projekt", "Aktivität", "Dauer", "Beschreibung", "Symbol"};

                JButton button[] = new JButton[label.length];
                JTextField textfield[] = new JTextField[label.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
                    button[i] = new JButton(label[i]);
                }   

                contentPanetagesliste.add(button[0], "1, 1");
                contentPanetagesliste.add(button[1], "2, 1");
                contentPanetagesliste.add(button[2], "3, 1");
                contentPanetagesliste.add(button[3], "4, 1");
                contentPanetagesliste.add(button[4], "5, 1");
                contentPanetagesliste.add(button[5], "6, 1");

                EintragStringPK = "Neu";                        

                for (int key=0; key<=ProjektJSONlength;key++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObjectProjekteObjekt0 = jsonObjectEintrag.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(key));  
                    String Eintraege = jsonObjectProjekteObjekt0.toString();
                    String EintragStringDauer = jsonObjectProjekteObjekt0.getString("dauer");  // String auslesen!!!                            
                    String EintragStringBEschreibung = jsonObjectProjekteObjekt0.getString("beschreibung");  // String auslesen!!!      
                    String EintragStringProjektname = jsonObjectProjekteObjekt0.getString("projektname");  // String auslesen!!!                            
                    String EintragStringAktivitaet = jsonObjectProjekteObjekt0.getString("kategorie");  // String auslesen!!!                           
                    EintragStringPK = jsonObjectProjekteObjekt0.getString("pk_ei_id");  // String auslesen!!!               

                    System.out.println("test" + key);
                    System.out.println(ProjektJSONlength);  
                    String labelCONTENT[] = {EintragStringPK, EintragStringProjektname, EintragStringAktivitaet, EintragStringDauer, EintragStringBEschreibung, "Symbol"};

                    for (int i = 0; i < labelCONTENT.length; i++) {
                        textfield[i] = new JTextField(labelCONTENT[i]);
                    }
                    int keypone = key+2;
                    String keyString = Integer.toString(keypone);
                    contentPanetagesliste.add(textfield[0], "1, "+keyString);
                    contentPanetagesliste.add(textfield[1], "2, "+keyString);
                    contentPanetagesliste.add(textfield[2], "3, "+keyString);
                    contentPanetagesliste.add(textfield[3], "4, "+keyString);
                    contentPanetagesliste.add(textfield[4], "5, "+keyString);
                    contentPanetagesliste.add(textfield[5], "6, "+keyString);
                }

                JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(contentPanetagesliste);
                frame.add(jsp);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                System.out.println("ende");
            }else{
                frame.setVisible(false);
                System.out.println("ende2");    
            }
            System.out.println("ende3");

        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("ende4");

    }
});
```

**Explanation:**

I create the JFrame, afterwards the JPanel.

Create an Array and the rest necessary for my Table, because the goal is to make a generated table with data from a SQL DB.

There is also a HTTPrequest and a loop to get out the data and put it into the table fields.
Still in the loop the filled table fields are added to the content pane and at the very and the Jpanel get's his JScrollPane and the frame is set visible.

*I really hope someone can help me, and if you got tips for making better questions I've got an open ear.*

Comment: i would suggest you create a JTable to hold the data and add the JTable to the scrollpane and the scrollpane to the JPanel and jpanel to JFrame

Comment: By "stuck" do you mean you can't move the window around? Or does the window become unresponsive? Just for clarification

Comment: I did so, but i get the error: invalid layout key, because i cannot add buttons to the scrollpanel it seems

Comment: @DonnachaConnolly The window becoms unresponsive, and when i move it it goes blank grey.

Comment: use a layoutmanager like BorderLayout. add the scrollpane to the center and buttons to the bottom

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Sadly I'm stuck at using this method for creating tables. Well the thing is, the table was added to the frame without a panel in between, and it worked perfectly. But sadly i need the Panel for the scrollpane. And now i need to know how the (i believe) panel interferes with the other frame/panel

Comment: your TableLayout seems to be a selfmade class. maybe that causes a problem

Comment: I just tested it. The problem is definetily because of the JPanel and no I didnt make it myself. Selfmade yes, but should work and not made by me

Comment: `setContentPane(contentPanetagesliste);` this should be explicit set to the new frame you created. @DonnachaConnolly that doesn't make any difference. i have a working code with that and it doesn't freeze

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I removed my comment if that's the case. I was almost certain I read that somewhere though, but i can't be certain

Comment: @DonnachaConnolly you can use the code i posted as an answer to check it yourself. only have to create a frame to can use to trigger the actionLsitener

Comment: *"There is also a HTTPrequest and a loop to get out the data"* - You are likely blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, prevent it from updating the UI - See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for a possible solution

Comment: Also have a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for a better general solution

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Sorry for the late reply and thanks because: "setContentPane(contentPanetagesliste); this should be explicit set to the new frame you created. " worked for me! That was the reason! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setContentPane(contentPanetagesliste);` should be explicit set to the new frame you created like this: `frame.setContentPane(contentPanetagesliste);`.

Comment: Thanks, but your previous comment helped, it was just the JPanel that wasn't set correctly that made the problems. Maybe you could change/edit your answer to this so i can accept it? :)